# Numbers : Conditional Highlighting with decimal

Tags: numbers, iwork

I have a cell, the value is 90.90,

I setup a continual highlighting for different value, one is suppose to be greater than or equal to 99.90.

however I don't get this one to work as 99.90 is automatically change to 99.9 (even though the cell remain to 99.90)

How can I fix it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is a mathematical formula, 99.90 is the same as 99.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this and even though 99.90 is changed to 99.9 in the conditional highlighting rule, it works perfectly even if the value in the cell is 99.90.
[image]

Comment: I have the exact same settings but its wasn't working and keep give me the colour of the wrong data, but for some reason it now in the correct colour (I didn't zero change) anyway. thank you.